# C# - Application Windows Service Crash

Tags: c#, .net, exception, service, stack-overflow

I have a project in C# built in Windows Service.
It works fine but it crash sometimes without any reason.

When i check Windows Event Viewer, the only thing i can see is :
[image: Application crash Log]

```
Nom de l’application défaillante <<MyApplicationName>>, version : 7.3.0.0, horodatage : 0x5f4ca7db
Nom du module défaillant : bcryptPrimitives.dll, version : 6.3.9600.18895, horodatage : 0x5a4b0740
Code d’exception : 0xc00000fd
Décalage d’erreur : 0x00001c1d
ID du processus défaillant : 0x1330
Heure de début de l’application défaillante : 0x01d67fc7fd46a198
Chemin d’accès de l’application défaillante : <<MyApplicationPath>>
Chemin d’accès du module défaillant: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
ID de rapport : a4242415-ec19-11ea-80ea-00155d0dc716
Nom complet du package défaillant : 
ID de l’application relative au package défaillant :
```

I have check the exception code `0xc00000fd` and it seems to be a Stack Overflow error. But i can't find where it crash, and i can't start the project in debug mode because it can crash in 3 days or in an hour.

What i have tried :

```
            try
            {
                
                ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
                Service service = new Service();
                ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
                {
                    service
                };
                if (Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName.Contains("vshost") || RUN_DEBUG)
                {
                    service.Start();
                    while (true) //Code to execute in debug mode, but not the problem
                    {
                        Task.Delay(1000);
                    }
                }
                else
                {                
                    ServicesToRun[0].AutoLog = true;
                    ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                string date = now.Year + "-" + now.Month + "-" + now.Day + "-" + now.Hour + "-" + now.Minute + "-" + now.Second;

                string stackTrace = "StackTrace-" + date + ".txt";
                string message = "ExceptionMessage-" + date + ".txt";
                string innerExceptionStackTrace = "InnerStackTrace-" + date + ".txt";
                string innerExceptionMessage = "InnerMessage-" + date + ".txt";

                if (!Directory.Exists("CrashReport-" + date))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory("CrashReport-" + date);
                System.IO.File.Create("CrashReport-" + date + "\\" + stackTrace).Close();
                System.IO.File.Create("CrashReport-" + date + "\\" + message).Close();

                File.AppendAllText("CrashReport-" + date + "\\" + stackTrace, ex.StackTrace);
                File.AppendAllText("CrashReport-" + date + "\\" + message, ex.Message);

                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                {
                    System.IO.File.Create("CrashReport-" + date + "\\" + innerExceptionStackTrace);
                    System.IO.File.Create("CrashReport-" + date + "\\" + innerExceptionMessage);

                    File.AppendAllText("CrashReport-" + date + "\\" + innerExceptionStackTrace, ex.InnerException?.StackTrace);
                    File.AppendAllText("CrashReport-" + date + "\\" + innerExceptionMessage, ex.InnerException?.Message);
                }
                 

                throw ex;
            }
```

My objective was to catch the error at the highest level of my application. But it didn't work.

I just make the service restart automaticaly when it crash, but i want to solve the bug.

Thank you for your help and sorry for my bad English.

**UPDATE :**

Moved the try catch section into the service. Service crashed again without report.

Executed the service in debug mode, no crash.
By the way, the service in normal execution crashed without any call on it.

Crash happen every ~9h. Too long for a normal stack overflow. I have no recursion in my code. The only thing i got in service code is a `While` with a `Thread.Sleep` for waiting new treatment

The service in debug mode is currently used, but it doesn't crash.
Is it a Service problem ?
Other services (C# too) running on this computer without any problem.

Comment: That is all the detail i get from this error, trying to find every log in every folder described in the event viewer, but absolutly nothing.

Comment: try adding an event handler for unhandled applicafion exceptions. the catch you currently have won't see exceptions in the service thread. show more code of the actual service thread, and add logging there. is there anything suspiciously dealing with cryptography, authentication, warranting a call into bcryptPrimitives.dll?

Comment: I'll try to move the try catch section into the service thread, i'll update the post if i have news (Update can be tomorow) . And i don't use any encryption in my service.

Comment: The stack overflow may be caused by too deeply nested calls (endless recursion) or too big local variables. You could detect both by adding checks. Count the recursion depth and supervise the size of local variables. Watch out for unintended recursion.

Comment: In that case, my try catch would report the error but my try catch never catch any errors.

Comment: The event log states the failing module is bcryptPrimitives.dll. Is your app using any cryptographic function? It is referenced in the project?
According to [this](https://www.file.net/process/bcryptprimitives.dll.html), there is a chance some malware camouflages itself as bcryptprimitives.dll.